# SharePoint 2013 - Content Organizer - File already exists in drop off library

Tags: content-organizer

If a file is stuck in the drop off library (e.g. because there is no matching rule to route the file,...), another file cannot be uploaded with the same name to the drop off library.

The error message we get is "A file with the name xxx already exists. It was last modified by XXX on XXX". Is there a good way to get around this?

I was thinking of creating an event receiver to programmatically rename the file name on ItemAdded.

Is there another better way? I don't think it can be done out-of-box SharePoint within the drop off library.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because the file is check out by the user who uploaded the document to the library and did not fill the required fields (drag and drop or through windows explorer)

Check target library settings>Manage files which have no checked in version